# Flash AS2 fullscreen problem

Tags: actionscript-2, fullscreen

i have my code to make the stage go to fullscreen but it doesn't seem to work if I use the .swf version of the file, if i export it as a .exe file though it will work, heres my function

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
    Stage.displayState = (Stage.displayState == "normal") ? Stage.displayState = "fullScreen" : Stage.displayState = "normal";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you set allowFullScreen=true in your embed params?

See - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode.html